# How to add custom sound in awesome notifications in iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, awesome-notifications

I'm using `awesome_notifications` package in pub dev and i successfully implemented this package in iOS and it is working perfectly well. Now the thing is i want custom sound play when notification receive in iOS physical device. I also added `.aiff` sound file inside `Runner` folder but no sound is coming when notification receives. Below is the sample dart code and what is missing link to implement custom sound notification in iOS.

```
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
                        content: NotificationContent(
                            id: 1,
                            channelKey: 'basic_channel',
                            title: 'Test',
                            body: 'test',
                            customSound: 'notification.aiff',
                            notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default),
                        actionButtons: [
                          NotificationActionButton(
                              key: 'MARK_DONE', label: 'Mark Done'),
                        ]);
```